# How do I make my own JavaScript functions have required parameters?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, coffeescript

When I'm writing javascript in intellij idea, I can check the parameters of a function I'm calling and it will say something like

[image: Optional arguments]

I'm not sure if this is an intellij feature where it knows about the standard library or if it's a javascript feature that lets you mark parameters as optional/required.  Either way, I'd like to learn how I can create my own functions with optional/required parameters.  All I know is that optional seems to be the default because Intellij says all my function's parameters are optional.

---

From the answers I'm seeing, it sounds like this is an Intellij feature.  But, now I'm wondering if Intellij provides a way for me to mark my own function arguments as optional/required.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are just concerned with the code completion bit then you can get that in the IntelliJ environment with the use of [JSDoc comments](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-jsdoc-comments.html). This does not affect your code, as others have pointed out you cannot specify to the JavaScript interpreter if a parameter is optional or not, but the editor will pick up the information from the comment and display it as you type. That way your own functions display similarly to the library functions.

Comment: In jsdoc, `@param {string} [somebody]` is an optional param whereas `@param {string} somebody` is required - search http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html for "Optional parameters"

Answer (score 12):

Using ES6 `default function parameters`, you can implement a `Required` FLAG, that will throw an error and stop execution, when a function with required parameters is called without providing them.

```js
// set a getter to a custom global identifier (P_REQUIRED)
Object.defineProperty( window , 'P_REQUIRED'  , {
  get : ()=>{
    let err     = new Error('');
    let trace   = err.stack.split('\n');
    let msg     = '';
    for(let i=2;i<trace.length;i++)  msg+=trace[i]+'\n';
    throw new Error('Missing required parameter\n' + msg); 
  },
  configurable : false
});


// declare a function with a mandatory parameter
function myFunc( myParam = P_REQUIRED ){
  /* some code here */
}

// call the function without the parameters
myFunc();
  
// Error is thrown!
```

Essentially, `P_REQUIRED` is assigned to the parameter by the interpreter, when no value has been specified in the function call. This triggers the getter handler, which simply prepares and throws a new Error.

It`s a clean and cross-browser solution, that will run in any modern environment (ES6 is required).

I actually packed it as a javascript module.
+info : https://github.com/colxi/P_REQUIRED

Comment: this should be the answer

Comment: On the last line of the `get`, any particular reason you are throwing a string instead of an error?

Comment: @DanielKaplan nope, just a mistake. Updated!

Comment: @Keslavi Unless intellij IDEA's autocomplete is aware of this pattern, I disagree. That said, I find this information valuable and have therefore upvoted it.

Answer (score 10):

Edit:  If you were to use something like [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) you could get this kind of checking.

This is impossible to do in JavaScript without literally checking for the expected arguments (as VoronoiPotato already showed).

Every JavaScript function has access to an `arguments` variable.  You can check to see if this has any arguments in it, and if they are of the types that you were expecting.

```
var foo = func(a, b) {

  if(arguments.length < 2 )
     Throw("error");

  if(typeof a !== '<expectedtype>' && typeof b !== '<expectedtype>')
     Throw("error");
};
```

Answer (score 8):

```
function foo(value1, value2){
/**
* @param myParam1 [Required]
* @param myParam2
*/
  if(value1 == undefined){
    throw('Value1 is a required field for function foo');
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure Intellij will use this code to tell me that value1 is required?

Comment: the basic idea here is to do the parameter validation inside the function so that you can provide your own custom, purposeful feedback, this seems like a standard approach to solving this problem...+1

Comment: if undefined is a valid value then it is an optional parameter.

Comment: I think what you're asking about the intellij is because those are the native javascript functions. Unless there's some kind of comment system for intellij autocomplete you can't do it.

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-jsdoc-comments.html and it looks like there is. However you're going to want to roll in errors for required fields as shown, it's good convention.

Answer (score 7):

I have another idea. I found this on some article.

create a function called **required()**;

```
function required(varName) {
    throw new Error(`${varName} is required. `);
}
```

And when a parameter is required , just use like this:

```
fnName(a=required("a"), b = required("b")){
    ....
    ...
}
```

Code example :

```js
function required(varName) {
    throw new Error(`${varName} is required. `);
}

function sumOfTwoValues(a= required("a"), b = required("b")){
   return a+b
}

console.log("sumOfTwoValues(1,2): ", sumOfTwoValues(1,2));
console.log("sumOfTwoValues(1): ", sumOfTwoValues(1));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const isRequired = () => { throw new Error('param is required'); };

const hello = (name = isRequired()) => { console.log(`hello ${name}`) };

// These will throw errors
hello();
hello(undefined);

// These will not
hello(null);
hello('David');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mandatory(params) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(params)) {
        if (!value) {
            throw Error(`Mandatory param error: ${key} can't be null`);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
functionThatRequiresParams = (paramA, param2) => {
    mandatory({paramA, param2});
    console.log('a ok');
}
```