# Why does the typescript compiler not always match function signatures

Tags: typescript

Why does the typescript compiler not always match function signatures as per the examples below:

```js
type Func = (a: string, b: number)=>void

//flagged as expected
const func1: Func = true

//not flagged as expected
const func2: Func = (a,b)=>console.log(a,b)

//flagged as expected
const func3: Func = (a:number,b:string)=>console.log(a,b)

//why is this not flagged as b is a required parameter and not optional?
const func4: Func = (a)=>console.log(a)
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMZQLxQBQEMBcUDOwATgJYIDmANFAEZ4JwC2NERAlKgHwBuA9iQBMAsAChRAenEAzADZZy5CAKhZ8UCAA9ISYEtFJeCQlCmIkARjzxkaKMTgRRE8Ql7ATchUpVrN23cIiBkbupsgATFZmttiUNBycwfi8MhAAdDK85LHxTiKSsvKKyqrqWhA6ekGGxmFIAMxRNujYOAzMrHE4hKQUCUkp6ZnZWHFseZIA7gAWIFAkasDTC1CuoZ7FAPz6NaFmACxNKC1YCP01gxlZ2GeiQA)

Comment: Ask yourself what runtime error could occur if you invoked `func4('a', 1)`? And how would adding the unused argument `(a, b) => console.log(a)` improve that? The truth is the code is fine, it runs fine, and there's not actually any problem here.

Comment: @Alex Wayne, a lot of code that the typescript compiler rejects runs fine in javascript.  The point of the compiler is to ensure types match.  In this case the types do not match - yet typescript doesn't complain about it.  If the standard is "code runs fine" then func3 should also not be flagged.

Comment: `func3` is wrong, though. If you try to use `a` as number, when it's actually a `string` bad things will happen. There is no way to call `func4` or use the arguments passed to `func4` that will cause problems. They both run in this case, but that's not really the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `type` in `Function`, then JS / TS doesn't care about the parameter list, until you use them inside your function.

Because, JavaScript doesn't have function overloading, it doesn't care about number of parameters while calling the function.

For example,

```
function sayHello(name) {
    console.log(`Hello ${name}`)
}
sayHello("John")
sayHello("David", "Adams")
sayHello("Smith", "David", "Adams")
```

the above code will not throw any error, but the output will be

```
Hello John
Hello David
Hello Smith
```

There is no way to make Function Parameters as required in JS/TS but there are some workaround I found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748308/how-do-i-make-my-own-javascript-functions-have-required-parameters)

I would prefer using Objects instead of separate parameters to make it required / optional and handle the edge case inside it.

Refer [this Example in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgW2gXigbwLACgq6gMwEsAnAZ2AC4pzjCA7AcwBps8oAbOcgfipvobYAvtmz4ArnQDGwQgHs61OCAASEduzkAKNETLAmHLsCFV4SAJRUAbnMIATdKzyF8WzuQtOcbPFIWkcuwQAHSaDFoABmoaclAAJLok5EIJaB4mkRbOuKnqpNCYPr5Q-nSBwWFyEdHqmml6KVk5UCJYbaJYpMoxmjotjZRQAEQAUnIAFnTDwtlY2N2qddpFbINUY5PTLMVG5BsAygiEwBMz7RZAA)

Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters

Comment: Thank you Shri for your answer.  And your answer is a work around, however in my use case I require compile time type checking and not run time type checking.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @ShriHari's answer, think of a click handler function.

Something like this:

```
interface MyMouseEvent {
  x: number
  y: number
}

interface Element {
  onClick: (event: MyMouseEvent) => void
}
```

In this case your handler may not always care about the event object that is passed to it.

Sometimes you only care if function is called at all.

```
element.onClick = () => console.log('clicked')
```

And sometimes you need that event object.

```
element.onClick = (e) => console.log('clicked position', e.x, e.y)
```

Both these options are 100% type safe. There is no variable that has the wrong type.

When *calling* a function type *all* parameters must be provided. But when *implementing* a function type, your are not required to accepts all parameters. If you don't use them in your function there is no point in accepting them. So there isn't much value in enforcing that all parameters are present.

All that matters is that the parameters that do exist are the right type.