# How can this overloading works in typescript?

Tags: typescript, overloading

I'm new to typescript and started reading about typescript function/method overloading.The documentation says : **The implementation signature must be compatible with the overload signatures**.
For me the following signature for the `someMethod` method is not compatible with the provided implementation signature. If I try something like this:

```
   class TestClass {
      someMethod(stringParameter: string, numberParameter: number): void;
      someMethod(stringParameter: string): void {
          console.log(stringParameter)  
   }
```

i was expecting an error saying no implementation provided for the `someMethod(stringParameter: string, numberParameter: number): void;`.

but when i run this test program :

```
const test = new TestClass() ; 
test.someMethod('someString', 10);
```

I get the `"someString"` arg printed to the console.

Can you explain how this works ?

Answer (score 3):

A function that accepts fewer parameters is assignable to (or compatible with)  a function that accepts more parameters. [See this answer for info on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71136780/why-does-the-typescript-compiler-not-always-match-function-signatures/71151021#71151021).

So the fact that your implementation omits one parameter from the overload is allowed. Your implementation simply ignores that argument. Yes it's probably a mistake, but it's still type safe.

However, you can make the the implementation incompatible by changing the type of the second argument:

```
class TestClass {
    someMethod(stringParameter: string, numberParameter: number): void;
    // This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.(2394)

    someMethod(stringParameter: string, bad: string): void {
        console.log(stringParameter)  
    }
}
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBhcVoG8BQ0-QgHsBbeAWXiQAtCATACmQCcBLAOwHMAFMJsUpPCYAuAklacANNDYBXYgCMhPPgKGi5ioQEpRAN0ItaAblz4A9ObhUWMQnqEhCYWgRYc2YJLKbxotmUIkaGASAAcvFgUQPwB3Fmp-JBgWYjCY0jYkSMI2Nw8vH3gAOnoAJgBmAE4AFm1sMzwiUgpqOkZxdm5efkp1MQkOaQUXUWYu3WgDIyxG-DxQtiIY4qcODsGVXsEmbTw5gF9sA6A)

So the documentation is correct. But learning what type are "compatible" is not always as straightforward as you might think.

Comment: I blame that typing duck.. :)